# MailChimp API createCampaign

Tags: mailchimp

I have the template i want on a server somewhere, with images and all. How do I just use that as a template? or cant you use a zipped version with all the media like you would when manually setting up a campaign ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using mailchimp. you will be asked to upload an HTMl or create your own template. if you want you can create your own newsletter in HTML then upload the HTML in your mailchimp.

Minimize your HTML code due to compatibility and use the images that is uploaded in your server by specifying thier location like src="www.domainname.com/location/image.jpg"

Comment: Im sending the html content in the CONTENT html string from <html> to </html> is that correct?

Comment: This wont reallt work for what im trying. I need to give it a url with the correct html and images. the url will change based on a name the user types in. in the OPTIONs field there is url, i does not do any thing for me, but let me see what im doing wrong